# Java classes reference each other

Tags: java, class

I have two java class files. Each of them has methods the other one uses.

```
public class class1{
    class2 c2 = new class2(); 
    m1(){
        c2.ma(); 
        m2();
    }
    m2(){}
}

public class class2{
    class1 c1 = new class1();
    ma(){}
    mb(){
        c1.m2();
    }
}
```

The lines

```
class1 c1 = new class1();
```

and

```
class2 c2 = new class2();
```

refer to each other causing an infinite loop, resulting in a java.lang.StackOverflowError error.

Is there some way to have the classes refer to each other or do I have no choice but to transfer all of my methods into a single class?

Comment: Is this some kind of a practice program? If not, the cyclic references could probably be a code-smell. Do you really need both classes to depend on each other?

Comment: Check this pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Comment: A stack overflow has nothing to do with classes referencing each other. It is perfectly possible and supported by Java to do that. The Exception is caused by a too deep recursin, this can happen with one method/class as well.

Comment: *A stack overflow has nothing to do with classes referencing each other*. Not sure what you mean. The `StackOverflowError` is due to a a cyclic constructor call.

Comment: Exactly what I am saying, a StackOverflowError happens if you are to deep in the call stack. It is a runtime error and has nothing to do with the static class layout. In this specific example I guess it is caused by initializing even more classes. Having one of both static could help.

Answer (score 6):

As is said above, this is a sign of code smell.

Having a setter to set the method afterwards is not satisfactory, as you have an object in an indeterminate state, until the setters are called.

Although using a dependency framework such as Spring can help solve the above problem, if you use constructor injection, then you cannot have cyclic dependencies either! But at least when a bean is injected, you are sure it is not half constructed.

If you don't want to use a dependency injection framework, consider a factory pattern where both objects are created by a factory method, which returns a tuple (or a container object in the case of Java which has no native support for tuples) containing the fully constructed objects.

Comment: An excellent answer. 1+. I'm deleting my answer in favor of this one.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Just an aggregation of our answers. :)

Comment: @ChetanKinger: perhaps, but both your answers are better than mine. Mine got more votes for being the first, but it's wrong.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: it still boggles my mind that your answer was down-voted, and that mine is the only up-vote for that answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I believe that the lack of upvotes on my answer is due to the fact that I missed the train. The best time for upvotes is the first few minutes of answering a question and sadly, mine had a downvote in the first few minutes.  This may have mislead other's to believe that it's an incorrect answer. Thanks for your upvote that gives my answer a chance to compete.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to have the classes refer to each other or do I have
>   no choice but to transfer all of my methods into a single class?

In my opinion, cyclic references are a code-smell. See [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references) answer for an explanation. Take special note of the point about `cognitive load`.

The solution is to have one class depend on the other and delegate the calls to the other class :

```
public class class1{
    class2 c2 = new class2(); 
    m1(){
        c2.ma(); 
        m2();
    }
    m2(){}
}

public class class2{
    ma(){}
}
```

This way, you are not really transferring all the methods to one class but just composing `class2` into `class1`. Other classes that were depending on `class1` and `class2` only have to depend on `class1` instead.

Comment: Can the downvoter please let me know what is wrong with my answer? Does the downvoter understand `Java`?

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens is that you create an instance of `Class1` in the constructor,

- which creates an instance of `Class2` in the constructor,

  - which creates an instance of `Class1` in the constructor,

    - which creates an instance of `Class2` in the constructor,

      - et cetera.

Your constructors are recursingly creating instances, causing the call stack to flood, resulting in a `StackOverflowError`.

I assume you want an instance of `Class1` to hold a reference to an instance of `Class2` and vice versa?

In that case, you can just do this:

```
public class Class1 {

    private Class2 c2;

    public Class1() {
        this.c2 = new Class2(this);
    }
}

public class Class2 {

    private Class1 c1;

    public Class2(Class1 class1) {
        this.c1 = class1;
    }
}
```

---

Cyclic aggregations like this are often a sign of a bad design; but there *are* situations where it is perfectly valid, or at least reflects reality.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I bet you didn't see this coming :)

Comment: StackOverflow hah!